# Are these claims about Japan’s health system true?

Tags: healthcare, japan, public-health

The series of claims in the image below has been getting shared around Facebook and are posted from the "[Illuminati Exposed](https://www.facebook.com/exposetheilluminati)" page.

The claims are in the image but I've listed them here

> - 100% of Japanese people have health coverage, regardless of their income.
> - They spend half what the USA does.
> - They get to choose their own doctors, and see them twice as often as we do.
> - They have the world's longest life expectancy, and the second lowest infant mortality rate in the world.
> - 95% of Japan's healthcare is non-profit.
> - The Japanese government caps fees for medical services and pharmaceuticals.

[image]

For many readers of Skeptics, Illuminati Exposed may not seem credible, but many of its readers consider it credible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87908/discussion-on-question-by-user1605665-are-these-claims-about-japans-health-syst).

Comment: Beware that life expectancy data.  There are plenty of cases of those old people actually being dead and someone is pocketing the money they are getting.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Enough cases to shift considerably the life expectancy of a population of 125 million? I doubt that.

Comment: @Schmuddi Not the number of cases that have been found--but there's probably a lot more that haven't been found.  We simply don't know.

Comment: @LorenPechtel which happens in all countries, not just Japan. So unless you can show that it happens a lot more in Japan as compared to other countries, so much more in fact that Japan slips on the charts, the assertion is useless.

Comment: @jwenting There's other instances of Japan specifically having faulty social data. Their murder rate vs their "abandoned body" rate for example. Combined with a culture that reveres elderly enough that people actually lie about being *older*, it's a speculation that's worth looking into in a thorough answer.

Comment: Most developed nations have similar health care.  When it comes to how health care is funded and administered, America is, in fact, the exception and not the rule.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

## The gist of it is true

[Health Care System in Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_care_system_in_Japan)

### "100% of Japanese people have their healthcare regardless of income"

This is partially true. All are mandated to have coverage, but that coverage is not 100%, and not all have the mandated coverage.

> The health care system in Japan provides healthcare services, including screening examinations, prenatal care and infectious disease control, with the patient accepting responsibility for 30% of these costs while the government pays the remaining 70%.
>
> All residents of Japan are required by the law to have health insurance coverage. People without insurance from employers can participate in a national health insurance programme, administered by local governments.
>
> Uninsured patients are responsible for paying 100% of their medical fees, but fees are waived for low-income households receiving a government subsidy. Fees are also waived for homeless people brought to the hospital by ambulance.

### "They spend half what the USA does"

True. The amounts in the figure are the sums of [both out-of-pocket and government contributions](http://www.oecd.org/health/health-systems/Health-Spending-Latest-Trends-Brief.pdf) to healthcare expenditures.

[image]

### "They get to choose their own doctor"

True

> Patients are free to select physicians or facilities of their choice and cannot be denied coverage.

### "They [...] see them twice as often as we do"

It is [more than that](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/09/06/AR2009090601630_pf.html).

> The Japanese visit a doctor nearly 14 times a year, more than four times as often as Americans.

### "They have the worlds longest life expectancy"

True.

[List of countries by life expectancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy) — which is based on WHO numbers — puts Japan at #1.

### "They have [...] the second lowest infant mortality rate in the world"

According to the [CIA World Factbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_infant_and_under-five_mortality_rates#Infant_mortality_from_the_CIA_World_Factbook), true.

### "95% of japans health care is non-profit"

This claim is contentious, since it relies on how you define "health care". According to the Wikipedia page...

> Hospitals, by law, must be run as non-profit and be managed by physicians. For-profit corporations are not allowed to own or operate hospitals. Clinics must be owned and operated by physicians.

The contention here is if we should count "clinics" as part of the "health care", what profit rules apply to "clinics", and whether the government mandated health insurance covers visits to "clinics".

### "The Japanese government caps fees for medical services and pharmaceuticals"

True, according to the Wikipedia page:

> Medical fees are strictly regulated by the government to keep them affordable. Depending on the family income and the age of the insured, patients are responsible for paying 10%, 20%, or 30% of medical fees, with the government paying the remaining fee.
>
> Also, monthly thresholds are set for each household, again depending on income and age, and medical fees exceeding the threshold are waived or reimbursed by the government.

Comment: I've deleted a ton of political chit-chat in the comments. Reminder: at skeptics you are not welcome to discuss your political ideology (in this case on whether universal healthcare is beneficial or not). There's plenty of other forums to do that, kindly keep this place peaceful.

Comment: Interestingly Japan is similar to many other countries with universal healthcare. I honestly first thought that maybe the stats came from another country because I wasnt sure if Japans system works just like some in Europe.